# Insert the date into 2 tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have 2 tables like Item and Image, first table tbl_Item has 2 fields those are item code,item name and second table tbl_Image has 2 fields like item code and item image. I have fields like item code, item name, item image and one button. When i click the submit button those records are inserted into both two tables. I want to insert the data into two tables  How it is possible? Can any body suggest me?

```
    cmd.Connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[1].ToString());
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into tbl_item (@itemcode,@itemname) values(ItemCode,ItemName)";
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into tbl_image (@itemcode,@itemimage) values(ItemCode,ItemImage)";
```

Comment: Is that the real code, because I think you swapped parameters with column names, plus are you sure your table `Image` is not a view based on `tblItem` ?

Comment: _"When i click the submit button those records are inserted into both two tables"_ - are you sure about this? Do you only execute one query on button click? Does the database contain any triggers or is it indeed a view like @Habib says? This is too vague to solve, please show more info.

Comment: Thank you Habib, yes its a real code first of all i tried with two feilds then after i will add

Comment: Thank you CodeCaster, i dont know command exactly for two tables thats way i posted this one, we can insert data into only one table by using above command

Comment: there may be any code written on selection of image to insert image into 2nd table!

Comment: ya table Image is not a view based on tblItem

Comment: ThankYou SanjeevRai No

Comment: Can We insert data into 2 tables by using OnClick

Comment: I dont really get the english. What do you want? In the question you're inserting into two tables and then ask how is it possible to add into two tables. That makes no sense. Please explain what you want to do and what is happening.

Comment: Thank you Francisco Afonso Yes I want to inserting into two tables at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to insert both record in single command execution then join query with ";".

such as

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into tbl_item (@itemcode,@itemname) values(ItemCode,ItemName);insert into  tbl_image (@itemcode,@itemimage) values(ItemCode,ItemImage)";
```

Comment: The SQL query itself is wrong. It must be @"insert into tbl_item (ItemCode,ItemName) values(@itemcode,@itemname)";

Comment: ya i changed it Deniyal Tandel

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can insert into two tables simultaneously. Check this code:

**Note:** Your original insert query was wrong, I have modified it.

```
public void InsertIntoDataBase(int itemCode, string itemName, string itemImage)
{
    string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[1].ToString();
    string query1 = @"insert into tbl_item (ItemCode,ItemName) values(@itemcode,@itemname)";
    string query2 = @"insert into tbl_image (ItemCode,ItemImage) values(@itemcode,@itemimage)";

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

    try
    {
        // Exc]ecute the first query.
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query1, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@itemcode", SqlDbType.Int, 10, "ItemCode").Value = itemCode;   // Pass the actual Item code
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@itemname", SqlDbType.Text, 20, "ItemName").Value = itemName; //Pass the actual Item name
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


        // Exc]ecute the second query.
        cmd = new SqlCommand(query2, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@itemcode", SqlDbType.Int, 10, "ItemCode").Value = itemCode;   // Pass the actual Item code
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@itemimage", SqlDbType.Text, 20, "ItemImage").Value = itemImage;  // Pass the actual Item image
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you skumar it worked to me but here you pass the static values, i want to pass the values dynamically how?